# Minimize the norm of $w$.

Tags: calculus, normed-spaces

Why is minimizing the norm of $w$ equivalent to minimizing $\frac{1}{2} \cdot |w|^2$?

I have tried to derive the norm but the result is the following $$\frac{1}{2 \cdot |w|}$$

Comment: More or less a duplicate of this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1768566/why-does-a-distance-and-its-square-reach-their-minimum-at-the-same-point/

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** If $\vec{w} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then
$$
\|\vec{w}\| = \sqrt{\sum w_i^2} \text{ and }
\frac{1}{2}\|\vec{w}\|^2 = \frac{1}{2} \sum w_i^2
$$

So if one of them reaches minimum, what could you say about the other one? (Note, $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is an increasing function)

Comment: i think that (1/2)|w|^2 = (1\2)∑w^2

Comment: @user235204 thanks fixed

Comment: thanks for the support but i don't understand the 1/2, since i i readed that is the same to minimize |w| that minimize (1/2)|w|^2 i don't understand why? the 1/2 doesnt affect