# Why minimize squared L2 norm and not only the L2 norm?

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, inverse-problems

I'm studying Inverse Problems and usually, they minimize the squared of the L2 norm($L_2, L_0, L_ \infty$), why don't minimize only the norm? if the goal is to have a measure of the distance between 2 parameters?

Why they minimize this:
$\left \| m - m_{ref} \right \|_2^2$

instead of:

$\left \| m - m_{ref} \right \|_2 $

Comment: Similar (duplicate?): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1768566/why-does-a-distance-and-its-square-reach-their-minimum-at-the-same-point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squaring $\cdot^2\colon [0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ is strictly increasing function so minimum will be achieved at the same point: if $f\colon X\to [0,\infty)$, then $$f(m) \leq f(x), \forall x\in X \iff f(m)^2 \leq f(x)^2, \forall x\in X.$$
On the other hand, the square of the $2$-norm is nicer to handle since it gets rid of the square root in the definition of the $2$-norm.

Comment: I don't understand, in both equations, the minimum will be achieved at the same point? I see the practical utility of having the squared of the $L_2$ norm, but the result will be the same for both?

Comment: I'm not sure what you don't understand. If $f(m)$ is minimal, then $f(m)^2$ is minimal and vice versa. It doesn't mean that the value of the minimum is the same, if that's what is confusing you. @Jeniffer Barreto

Comment: @Jeniffer Barreto, for example, we can try to find minimum of $\sqrt{x^2+2}$. It will achieve its minimal value at the same point as $\sqrt{x^2+2}^2 = x^2+2$. Since $x^2+2\geq 2$, and the minimum is achieved at $x = 0$, the minimum of $\sqrt{x^2+2}$ is achieved at $x = 0$ as well. On the other hand the minimum of $\sqrt{x^2+2}$ is $\sqrt 2$, while the minimum of $\sqrt{x^2+2}^2$ is $2$.