# Why is minimizing the norm of an vector ($|w|$) the same as minimizing its sum of squares ($0.5 |w|^2$)?

Tags: calculus, optimization

Like the title says, im not sure why some popular machine learning textbooks say this. Is there something i am missing. I can elaborate if needed.

Similar to this question: [Minimize the norm of $w$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1256182/minimize-the-norm-of-w)

But i was not able to follow the answer.

Comment: Read more about requirements / properties of a norm. One of them is that norm is non negative, minimizing a non negative value is equivalent to minimizing its square.

Comment: Basically it's as simple as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1768566/why-does-a-distance-and-its-square-reach-their-minimum-at-the-same-point/1768643#1768643).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $f$ is a strictly increasing function then minimizing $f(g(x))$ is equivalent to minimizing $g(x)$. In your case, set $f: \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so that $f(x) = .5x^2$ and set $g: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so that $g(x) = |x|$. Then $f(x)$ is strictly increasing, so minimizing $|x|$ is equivalent to minimizing $.5|x|^2$.

Intuitively, just imagine if you're playing a game where there is some dollar payout for getting a high score, and the higher your score the more the payout.  No matter what the relationship is between the score and the payout, the strategy to make the most money is to get the highest score.

More formally:

**Lemma.** Let $g: A \rightarrow B$ be a function, with $A$ any set and $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and let $f: B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an increasing function, so that $x \leq y \implies f(x) \leq f(y)$. Then, if $x_0 \in A$ is such that $g(x_0)$ minimizes $g(x)$ then $f(g(x_0))$ minimizes $f(g(x))$.

*Proof*: Suppose $g(x_0)$ is a minimum.  Then for any $x$, $g(x_0) \leq g(x)$, and so since $f$ is increasing, $f(g(x_0)) \leq f(g(x))$.  $\square$

Note also that if $f$ is *strictly* increasing, with $x < y\implies f(x) < f(y)$, then $f$ "preserves uniqueness" in the sense that if $x_0$ is the unique minimizer of $g$ then $x_0$ is also the unique minimizer of $f\circ g$. [exercise]